# duplicate rows based on a column value

Tags: postgresql

Rather than merging rows I need to 'expand' rows, here's an example to explain:

```
|Material|count|  
|Rock    | 3   |  
|Gold    | 2   |   
|Silver  | 1   |   
|Wood    | 2   |
```

I need one row per material e.g. translated to this

```
|Material|count|   
|Rock    | 1   |   
|Rock    | 1   |   
|Rock    | 1   |   
|Gold    | 1   |   
|Gold    | 1   |   
|Silver  | 1   |   
|Wood    | 1   |   
|Wood    | 1   |
```

Is there an sql solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `generate_series()` it's cunningly easy:

```
select t.material, 1 as count
from t, generate_series(1, t.count) ;
```

Test in **[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7de8c/1)**.

Answer (score 3):

You need a sufficiently large table to multiply the source table. In your example it is sufficient to do a self join:

```
select material, 1 
from (
    select x.material, x.count
         , row_number() over (partition by x.material) rn 
    from t as x 
    cross join t as y
) as u 
where rn <= count 
order by material;

Gold               1
Gold               1
Rock               1
Rock               1
Rock               1
Silver             1
Wood               1
Wood               1
```

PostgreSQL also have a nifty table function generate_series that can be used:

```
select material, 1 from (
    select t.material, t.count
         , row_number() over (partition by material) as rn 
    from t 
    cross join generate_series(1,10)
) as u 
where rn <= count
order by material;
```

instead of 10 you can determine:

```
select max(count) from t
```

and use that to avoid creating an unnecessary large table.

While educating myself I realized that generate_series can take a variable as argument:

```
select material, 1 from (
    select t.material, t.count
         , row_number() over (partition by material) as rn 
    from t 
    cross join ( SELECT  generate_series(1, cnt)
                 FROM ( SELECT MAX(COUNT) FROM t ) u (cnt)
               ) as v 
) as u 
where rn <= count
order by material;
```

Using LATERAL means we can correlate cnt with count in the outmost table, and thereby remove the need for row_number():

```
select material, 1 
from (
    select t.material, t.count
    from t 
    cross join LATERAL ( SELECT  generate_series(1, cnt)
                         FROM ( 
                             SELECT COUNT 
                             FROM t as t1
                             WHERE t.material = t1.material 
                         ) u (cnt)
                       ) as v 
) as u 
order by material;
```

If you made it this far, go read @ypercubeᵀᴹ answer. It does'nt get much simpler or better than that. Please vote for that one.

Comment: The solutions using `generate_series()` can be (vastly) simplified ;)

Comment: Yes, I feel I should shoot my self after seeing your solution:-)

Comment: My `,` is a hidden `cross join lateral` so the two queries (mine and your last one) are essentially doing the same thing)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7de8c/9

Comment: Is it true in general that you don't have to use LATERAL in psql when selecting from a function returning a table? Db2 requires a TABLE (synonym for LATERAL, but oddly enough it does not accept LATERAL in this context)?

Comment: In Postgres, yes. In DB2 or standard SQL no idea

Comment: This solution works, but the generate_series is even simpler, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

First create udf function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ReturnVal]
(
@Input INT
)
RETURNS @Data  TABLE (
val INT
)
AS 
Begin
    Declare @IntialVal INT=1,
            @count INT=@Input
    WHILE (@IntialVal <= @count)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Data
        SELECT 1
        SET @IntialVal=@IntialVal+1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Sample Data and Sql query

```
DECLARE  @TempData AS TABLE (Material Varchar(100),[count] INT)
INSERT INTO @TempData
SELECT 'Rock'  , 3 UNION ALL    
SELECT 'Gold'  , 2 UNION ALL     
SELECT 'Silver', 1 UNION ALL      
SELECT 'Wood'  , 2    

SELECT d.Material,
        1 AS [count]
FROM @TempData d
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[udf_ReturnVal](d.[count])
```

Expected Result

```
Material    count
-----------------
Rock         1
Rock         1
Rock         1
Gold         1
Gold         1
Silver       1
Wood         1
Wood         1
```

Comment: Have you verified your solution against psql? It looks as if your answer is for sql-server.

Comment: Square brackets, `dbo` schema, `CROSS APPLY`, lack of statement terminators ... Looks like a SQL Server answer, not a Postgres one.